# Why is inline JavaScript security bad?

Tags: javascript, security

I know that inline JS is bad for performance, but why is it bad for security? Can you please explain to me why? With some examples?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is inline script forbidden (Content Security Policy)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15780918/why-is-inline-script-forbidden-content-security-policy)

Answer (score 5):

A restrictive [content security policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) can help to reduce the impact of script injection vulnerabilities by disallowing all scripts except those with a certain hash¹.

- If you use inline JavaScript in the form of `on*` attributes or `javascript:` URLs, you can’t implement this type of policy at all, so that’s definitely less safe.
- If you use inline JavaScript in the form of `<script>`s without a `src`, it’s less convenient to create a hash or nonce for use in a CSP, which might tempt people not to add one at all. A nonce policy also allows for dynamic scripts, which are generally bad ideas (just about the only use for dynamic scripts – inserting JSON in a `<script>` because it *looks* compatible with JavaScript – is a recipe for bugs and script injection²).

<sub>¹ or located on a certain domain that you only use for *static* content. careful about allowing domains (including the origin!) serving user content that can act as scripts!</sub>
<sub>² caused by not escaping `<`, U+2028, and U+2029 – JSON’s 3 incompatibilities with inline JavaScript. I recommend using your typical HTML escaping and reading from a `data-` attribute instead.</sub>