# UI5 application security advice

Tags: javascript, html, security, sapui5

In the OpenUI5 documentation is [written](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/fe12df2e338e43598977d09f3d191b7b):

> *Now, we create a new `index.js` script that will contain the application logic for this tutorial step. We do this **to avoid having executable code directly in the HTML file for security reasons**. This script will be called by the `index.html`. We defined it there as a module in a declarative way.*

In other words, the official OpenUI5 documentation advices to extract the following code:

```js
<script>
    "use strict";
    sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
        new sap.m.Shell("", {
            appWidthLimited: false,
            app: new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer("", {
                name: "webapp",
                height: "100%"
            })
        }).placeAt("content");
    });
</script>
```

into a separate JS-file:

```js
"use strict";

sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(() => {

    new sap.m.Shell("", {
        app: new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer("", {
            height: "100%",
            name: "webapp"
        }),
        appWidthLimited: false
    }).placeAt("content");

});
```

I'm curious to know how exactly extracting the JS-code from the HTML-page into a separate JS-file can contribute to the UI5 application security?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is inline JavaScript security bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48672542/why-is-inline-javascript-security-bad)

Comment: In short; removing inline script allows us to enable strict [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP).

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann, thanks. Do I understand it correctly that even one tiny inline script within `<script>…</script>` will disable the CSP?

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann, do I need to enabled CSP via `<meta>` in the HTML page or just send appropriate headers by the server?

Comment: About `<script>…</script>`: Yes, having the `Content-Security-Policy` header alone will skip executing **any** inline scripts, unless you add the `unsafe-inline` policy explicitly. You can add `<meta>` in `index.html` for a demo, but AFAIK the recommended way is to add the policy in the header by the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is an extra explanation on it in the [UI5-documentation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/1f81a093a9f3433983dcb2ebe11cd4cd):

> *It's strongly recommended that you make your OpenUI5 applications CSP compliant — after all, you want your apps to be secure. The main thing you have to do is to remove all scripts that directly execute code from your HTML pages.*
>
> *Don't use directly executable code in your HTML files, because this makes them vulnerable. Instead, enable the `ComponentSupport` module in the bootstrapping script. Then, declare your desired component in the body via a `div` tag. This will instantiate the component when the `onInit` is executed.*

More details regarding the Content Security Policy (CSP) and hand-on examples:

- https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy
- https://content-security-policy.com/